# Geting inserted data of text field into a listview in the previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter , i am trying to get the data inserted in the text field into a list and show this list into the previous screen.

I had made two screen in first screen we navigate to the first screen and on  second screen i have three text fields from witch i want to fetch the data into a new list and show this list into the previous screen someone if getting what i am trying to say please help thanks in advance.

this is my main page

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'second.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/Data": (BuildContext context) => new Data()
  }));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("NOTE bOOK"),
          ),
          body: new Container(
          ),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Data");
              },
              child: new Icon(Icons.add))),
    );
  }
```

this is my second page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_apptasktwo/main.dart';

class Data extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DataState createState() => _DataState();


}

class _DataState extends State<Data> {
  List<String> messages = List();
  var _textController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff84FFFF),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new
            TextField(
              controller : _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Hint text '
                )
            ),

            new
            TextField(
                controller : _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Hint date'
            )

            ),
            new
            TextField(
                controller : _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Hint discription '
            ),

            ),

            FloatingActionButton(

              onPressed: () {

                Navigator.pop(context ,MyApp());
                                            },
              child: Icon(Icons.save),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,

            ),
          ],
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried to implement.

Comment: ssir i have added the code if you have time please make a look ...thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String returned = 'Retuned text will appear here..';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Returning Data Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(children: [
        Text(returned, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var someValue = await Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (con) => SelectionScreen()));
            print(someValue);
            if (someValue != null && someValue.toString().isNotEmpty) {
              setState(() {
                returned = someValue.toString();
              });
            }
          },
          child: Text('Get Values', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        )
      ])),
    );
  }
}

class SelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectionScreenState createState() => _SelectionScreenState();
}

class _SelectionScreenState extends State<SelectionScreen> {
  TextEditingController c1, c2, c3;
  //and son on....

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    c1 = TextEditingController();
    c2 = TextEditingController();
    c3 = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pick an option'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: c1,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: c2,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: c3,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the screen and return "Nope!" as the result.
                  Navigator.pop(context, [c1.text, c2.text, c3.text]);
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```